# SQL Server Compact 3.5 sp2 license

Tags: sql-server-ce

has anyone of you some information about licensing and/or redistribution rights for the MS SQL Server Compact 3.5 sp2?

There is nothing to find on MS web-page so I try my luck here.

Chris

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 is freely redistributable under a redistribution license agreement. Application developers redistributing SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 can optionally register (but link is broken)- http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5783